# How can I filter tests in our Gradle build on Jenkins without commits?

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, build.gradle

I have a Gradle build that runs a suite of Java Selenium tests on Jenkins.  Since timing can cause Selenium test failures, I rerun failures a time or two.

To do this, I use Gradle's test filtering mechanism, e.g.:

```
test {
    [...]
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching "*AccountTest.canWithdrawMoney*"
    }
    [...]
}
```

But this means I have to make a Git commit with the filter.

In theory I can also use a command line filter like this:

```
gradle test --tests "*AccountTest.canWithdrawMoney*"
```

The trouble is that I don't call `gradle test` to run the tests.  I call my own tasks `gradle testLocal` or `gradle testServer`, depending on whether I'm running tests on my local PC or the Jenkins server, and the respective task calls `test`.

(The Jenkins server has to do extra things such as download and start our product; locally I have it running already.)

If I try...

```
gradle testLocal --tests "*AccountTest.canWithdrawMoney*"
```

...then it fails with...

> Unknown command-line option '--tests'.

...presumably because `testLocal` and `testServer` aren't (type: Test) tasks (nor do I want them to be).

I'd be happy to have the test filter be a Jenkins build parameter, as the build is already parameterized, but I can't figure out a way to get the filter to Gradle.

So: Given this setup, is there a simpler way I can pass in a test filter to Gradle which won't require me to add the filter as a Git commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to lance-java for helping me get there, but I couldn't get his solution to work until I put it in a `doFirst` block in the `test` task.  I also modified it to work with multiple classes and tests.

The final version that worked for me was:

```
test {
    [...]
    doFirst {
        def testFilter = System.getProperty('testFilter')
        if (testFilter) {
            def testFilterParts = testFilter.split(',')
            testFilterParts.each {
                item ->
                    filter {
                        includeTestsMatching item
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    [...]
}
```

I used the equivalent of this filter in the Jenkins testFilter parameter:

```
*TestClassA.methodA*,*TestClassB.methodB*,*TestClassC.methodC*
```

Comment: By the way, this does _not_ work if you use backticks to put spaces in your test names.  Possibly there's somewhat different syntax that would work even in that case, but I haven't had an opportunity to look into it.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
test {
    [...]
        def testFilter = findProperty('testFilter')
        if (testFilter) {
            filter {
               includePatterns = testFilter.split(',')
            } 
        } 
    [...]
}
```

And run using

```
gradle testLocal -PtestFilter=*AccountTest.canWithdrawMoney*
```

Comment: It works!  I had to put it within a `doFirst` section to get it to work.

Comment: Any idea how I can get it to work with multiple tests or test classes?  I've tried passing them in as a comma-separated string (with or without * wildcards) and splitting them in the build script and rejoining them, surrounding each one by quotes...but so far I just get "No tests found for given includes" in every attempt.

Comment: After 17 attempts (thank for nothing, terrible Gradle docs), I figured out how to get it to work with multiple (comma-separated) test filters.  I've taken the liberty of updating your answer with that.

Comment: Shouldn't need `System.setProperty(...)` also shouldn't need `doFirst{...}`. This is a configuration time operation. doFirst occurs at execution time

Comment: OK, well, when I tried again with what you now have above, it didn't work; it ran all the tests, not just the specified ones.  My test filter was the equivalent of this: `*TestClassA.methodA*,*TestClassB.methodB*,*TestClassC.methodC*`